# pt-table-checksum generates no output

Tags: mysql, replication, percona, percona-tools

I've been using pt-table-checksum on our staging server successfully, but when I run

```
./pt-table-checksum h=localhost,u=user --ask-pass --lock-wait-time=50 --databases prod
```

It just sits there. No output. Nothing in 'top'.

Any ideas where I should start looking? Thanks.